# SSH Command behaves differently in Expect Script

Tags: bash, ssh, scripting, expect

I'm using this command on Server1

```
~# ssh root@Server2 /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

to append the contents of Server2's `id_rsa.pub` to the `authorized_keys` of Server1.

It works if I do it manually but when I do it in an expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 60

spawn ssh root@[lindex $argv 0] cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

expect "yes/no" { send "yes\r" 
expect "*?assword" { send "[lindex $argv 1]\r" }
    } "*?assword" { send "[lindex $argv 1]\r" }
interact
```

What happens when I use the script is that the `id_rsa.pub` of Server2 is appended over the `authorized_keys` of Server2.

What would be the correct syntax?

Comment: you forgot the word cat in first example. Please paste working code (or broken where appropriate, but paste the code you tested).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like expect is not a shell, so it passes `>>` as an argument to ssh instead of interpreting it.

Try `spawn bash -c "ssh root@[lindex $argv 0] cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys"`